# React onClick not working in any of my browsers, but for colleagues it does

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

I've created an `onClick` handler in a very simple React function component:

```
export default function MyButton() {
   return (
      <button
         onClick={() => {
            console.log('test');
         }}
      >
         Button
      </button>
   );
}
```

Now the weird part: no matter what browser I use, the event is not firing. I've created such a component hundreds of times and everything was good, until now.

For everyone else this code works, as it was intended.

I cannot share the whole project or an example repository. It's really nothing but a simple React app you see everywhere.

What could be the reason for why it's not working on my system?

EDIT:

The error was somehow within yarn. I called `webpack-dev-server -d source-map --mode=development` for development and I am using `"webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0-beta.0"`. I think the cache could've gotten corrupted somehow.

To fix it, I removed my output directory and started the script with `npm` instead of `yarn`. This way it worked, even when I use `yarn` again.

I really don't know why this happened. Would be happy to know why.

Comment: Seems valid. We would need to reproduce it to troubleshoot. How is your project different from this: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hellman-b2czt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: there is no difference, but the build tool I guess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and the reason of the issue (in my case , probably yours ) is HtmlWebpackPlugin, HtmlWebpack Plugin is adding a addition script tag of bundle in head tag of index.html.

### my html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my-react-app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### htmlwebpackplugin generated html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my-react-app</title>
  <script defer src="bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

because of this additional script tag, there was a problem in react (i read a post on reddit  regarding to this problem and he also have multiple script of same bundle and he was having the same problem), i solved it by deleting my script tag, but we can use copywebpack plugin to just copy html. Or other solution is to configure htmlwebpackplugin suck a way that it will not inject any addition tags

```js
...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      name: "index.html",
      inject: false,
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
    }),
...
```

Comment: Yes issue with 'HtmlWebpackPlugin' . add inject: false issue will fix

Answer (score 1):

Use named function instead of anonymous function. Named functions are very useful for identifying what functions caused errors during development as well as when retrieving logs from your users.

```
import React from "react";

export default function MyButton() {
  const handleChange = () => {
    console.log("test");
  };
  return <button onClick={handleChange}>Button</button>;
}
```

It is a good practice to name-all-functions for a better developer debugging (and development) experience which anonymous function does not provide.

For more clarification between Named and Anonymous function [Learn the benefits of Named vs Anonymous function here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/javascript-named-vs-anonymous-functions-chris-ng/)

Comment: I did so, just posted it this way to simplify the problem :)

Comment: Great, then there might be some issues with your packages. Try debbuging the root cause :)

Answer (score 0):

Try typing your function as React.FC.

Create a typescript (tsx) file and use the upcoming code:

```
import React from "react";

export const MyButton: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("test");
      }}
    >
      Button
    </button>
  );
};
```

Note that using this code, you are typing the component making sure that your function is typed as React.FunctionComponent.

Answer (score -3):

Did you import this in your file, if not then add this tine on top

import React from 'react';

Comment: He told that it's working for others then i guess there is some other problem

Comment: Hm may be there is some other problem